# The best_in_place is not working on Heroku, and no error appears

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5, best-in-place

I would appreciate any help. This is the repository of this project: https://github.com/felixpro/ars-reclama

The best_in_place is working fine in development production but when I deploy it to Heroku it doesn't work. When I click on the best_in_place input, nothing happens.

thank you

aplication.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place.purr

//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

gemfile

```
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem "best_in_place"
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'draftsman', '~> 0.7.1'
```

show.html.erb

```
       <h1 class="name">
          <%= best_in_place @customer, :name%>
        </h1>
        <div class=" space email display_box">
          <%=image_tag("envelope.png")%>
          <p><%= best_in_place @customer, :email %></p>
        </div>
        <div class=" space doc display_box">
          <%=image_tag("doc.png")%>
          <p><%= best_in_place @customer, :doc %></p>
        </div>
```